# Error: no match for operator[]. While comparing int to int in list<int>,

Tags: c++, list

I'm trying to compare the integers in a list to integers but for some reason I get the error: no match for operator[], and I don't understand why. I have simplified what I have been trying to do below, but it's still the same core issue I have. Here is the code:

```
int main(){
    list<int> myBinaryList;
    int count;
    for (count = 0; count < 4, count++){
    myBinaryList.push_back(1)
    }
    //now I should have a list that looks like: (1, 1, 1, 1)

    for (auto const& i:myBinaryList){
        if (myBinaryList[i]==1){ //it's on this row that I will get the error
        myBinaryList[i]=0;
        }
    }

   return 0;
   }
```

Why do I get this error and how do I compare integers to integers in a list?

Comment: Use a `std::vector`, they have random access, `std::list` doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems:

1. `std::list` does not have an indexing operation.
2. A range-based loop iterates over a container's *elements*, not its indices.

You should almost never use `std::list` - `std::vector` is almost always the appropriate alternative - and your loop should look like this:

```
for (auto& element: myBinaryList){
    if (element == 1){ 
        element = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest using a different name than `i`. I understand this is for compatibility with the original code, but using `i` for elements instead of indices is very abnormal and confusing.

Comment: Okay thank you for your answer! Just a quick question. Why is it almost more appropriate to use vector rather then list?

Comment: @Programming_Zeus Linked lists are slow for general use on a modern machine, and a linked list of `int` wastes *a lot* of space (with double links and a 64-bit machine, around six times what's necessary).

Comment: @–Programming_Zeus Depends on what you want https://thispointer.com/difference-between-vector-and-list-in-c/

Comment: @Programming_Zeus  If you've come to C++ from a Python background, it may be worth mentioning that the implementation of Python _lists_ is much closer to C++ vectors than to C++ _lists_. This is because vectors are generally more efficient (unless you want to be able to randomly insert new items into the middle of an already large existing structure).